# Water flow in faults

Tags: geology, hydrology

Can water flow from a point 1200 meters above sea level, through fissures or faults below  sea level for a distance of 8 km and follow the fault upwards to a point 300 meters above sea level?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about worldbuilding.

Comment: Hint: [communicating vessels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_vessels).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can as long as you have enough water to fill the fault completely it can go up to 1199.9 meters above sea level.

It works as long as your out put is below your input because in total the water lowers down this has been used to supply households with water before pumps where common place.

It is still used in skyscrapers like the ones in Manhattan.

[this explains it with visuals](https://people.howstuffworks.com/water.htm)